# For failed command any sub-shell will get created?

Tags: shell

For failed command any sub-shell will get created? Suppose I given command like  ./ varprog.sh I got output as following
bash: ./: Is a directory 
which is correct and my command is fail. So I am curious for failed command any sub-shell is getting generated?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but first, define what you mean by a **failed command**. A command which is syntactically incorrect? A program which can't be started? A command which runs, but returns a non-zero exit code? A program, which writes something to stderr? Or whatever you consider a failure. But by and large, you determine when you want to have  a subshell. They don't magically spring into existence by some kind of failure.....

Comment: @user1934428. Thank you for your reply. To be more specific varprog.sh is my shell script. Which I run like ./ varprog.sh here my command will not execute as there is space between / and varprog.sh. So I got output as 'bash: ./: Is a directory'. In this case sub-shell will get generated or not?

Comment: Ah, no, there won't be generated one. Bash needs to set up a command to be executed, and it failed, so nothing executed, hence no child process created. Since a subshell is a special case of a child process, a subshell isn't generated either. Note also that the special variable `SHLVL` always shows the depth of the bash subshell, so you can always verify how deep down you are in the "subshell stack".

Answer (score 0):

There should be no space between "./" and "varprog.sh". So correctly you'd run you script as:

```
./varprog.sh
```

Does that help you?

Comment: Thank you for answer but I purposefully keep the space in between "./" and "varprog.sh". So that script will not execute. I want to know that in this case sub-shell will get generated or not?

Comment: I do not know. I guess your question can be reduced to: does bash create a "separate execution environment" when interpreting the command line?

I think that you can only find out by looking at the shell source code.

man bash: "...COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT...When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment".

The shell (here: bash) probably won't create a subshell in the precise semantics of "(echo subshell here)". And certainly won't create a separate process for it.